# Symbol to Break Steps to Solve Equation Apart in the Same Line?

Tags: notation

Is there a symbol for solving an equation that breaks each step? Usually this is done as a new line, like the following:

```
4x + 2 = 5
    4x = 3
     x = 3/4
```

I'm looking for a universal symbol that could change the above to look like this:

```
4x + 2 = 5 [SYMBOL] 4x = 3 [SYMBOL] x = 3/4
```

I've asked several math teachers throughout the years in school and none knew the answer.

Comment: How about: $\iff$

Comment: Would a ; (semicolon) be correct? I know "equations" (lines) in programming languages end in semicolons.

Comment: No. You need to use something that makes clear the connection of one statement to the next, and a semicolon doesn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such symbol in general, though in some cases $\iff$ or $\text{iff}$ (meaning *if and only if*) are technically correct. In general, however, it’s preferable to use words:

> $4x+2=5$, so $4x=5-2=3$, and therefore $x=\frac34$.

In general you should think of a mathematical argument as a piece of expository prose, and you should use enough linking expressions to make the flow of the argument clear.